# get validationDefault from model in CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I try to make a JsValidate helper, then I need access to validationDefault wrote on my Models table.php, how I can access?

I try

```
$model = TableRegistry::get($model);
$rules = $model->validationDefault();
```

but don't work.

I use CakePHP 3.0 ( PHP 5.5 )

Answer (score 1):

You get the validation object by doing:

```
$rules = $table->validator('default');
```